# InvalidCastException on a explicit cast inside a assembly loaded by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, assemblies, .net

We're loading assemblies dynamically on demand by reflection
By now, we've defined five dll's and all have been preloaded by `Assembly.LoadFile()`.
In one of these assemblies, we have a defined an interface `IDeviceConnection`, which inherits from `IConnection` (which is defined in a contracts project that is used by the application and the assemblies).

We have managed to create an instance of `ParameterManager`, which is defined in the exact same dll as the `IDeviceConnection` interface. But as soon as we try to cast a `IConnection` to a `IDeviceConnection`, the application crashes telling us that it was not able to cast `IConnection` to `IDeviceConnection`, although it *is* a IDeviceConnection. Calling connection.GetType().GetInterfaces() shows several interfaces, which contains `IConnection` *and* `IDeviceConnection`.

Any hints were we could start investigating in this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do they contain any type? for ex. IDeviceConnection<T type> ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681003/invalidcastexception-when-creating-an-instance-using-assembly-createinstance check this

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this one out. Helped us a lot!